# How to use jsdoc for a meteor application

Tags: javascript, meteor, documentation, jsdoc

What is the correct way to use JSDoc within a meteor application?
Below there is my way to document the code, but there is no 'connection' between all parts.
Everything belongs to the example template, so the output of jsdoc should be structured correctly.

How can I improve this documentation?

```
Template.example.helpers({
    /**
     * Get all categories
     * @name        categories
     * @return      {Cursor}
     * @summary     Cursor categories
     */
    categories() {
        return Categories.find({});
    },
});

Template.example.onCreated(
    /**
     * If template is created (still not rendered), ReactiveDict variable is initialized
     * @function
     * @name        onCreated
     * @summary     Set ReactiveDict
     */
    function() {
        this.something = new ReactiveDict();
    }
);

Template.example.events({
    /**
     * Clicking on category will show a console message
     * @event
     * @summary     Console message
     */
    'click #category': (event, template) => {
        console.log('nice')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where I work, we encountered the same situation a few months ago, what we concluded was that `jsdoc` was just not adapted to auto-doc with `Meteor`'s implementation. We ended up using https://github.com/fabienb4/meteor-jsdoc which gives us full satisfaction.
It basically extends `jsdoc` syntax with meteor specific keywords so you can specify what is a `Meteor.call`, what is a collection helper and so on. Once configured and running, the output is basically what Meteor's documentation used to look like before 1.3 (as the author says, it's "Based on the templates from Meteor own docs.").

Edit: As we don't use Meteor's templating system, I don't have an existing example but I adapted a collection helper to your case, tell me if there is anything unclear. The trick is to play with `@memberOf`, `@isMethod`, etc depending on how you want your doc to be displayed.

```
   /**
     * @memberOf Foo Template
     * @summary Returns Bar conversation attached to stuff
     * @param {String} fooId
     * @param {Boolean} forced # Use to create foo when it's not found
     * @returns {Object} Bar
     */
    getStuff: function(fooId, forced=false) {
            'use strict';
           /** your code **/
    }
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example for my sample code? I don't know for what I should use `isTemplate` and how should I mark the `events`...

Comment: @ko0stik meteor-jsdoc is deprecated and I’m not sure if it supports react. Could you share if you found any other solution?

Comment: @cenk unfortunately, I stopped using Meteor so I can't help you much on this matter.